# Lumia 950 Windows 10 phone randomly redialling numbers

Tags: lumia-950

My Lumia 950 win 10 phone sometimes starts redialling random numbers over and over, sometimes as much as 10 or more times.  I discover this when next looking at my phone.  Sometimes this happens during the night but it can happen any time.
Has my phone been hacked?

Comment: I don't think your phone has been hacked. Does your phone has any other strange behaviours, like opening random apps ? In last resort you could try to hard reset your phone (make a backup first so you'll be able to recover your content).

Comment: @Michael thanks your response. Fortunately my phone is new so there's not much on board.  If the problem continues I will perform a hard reset as you suggest. Cheers, Art

Comment: great, let us know if it resolves the problem...!